# Python: Sum numbers in nested list between separators EDITED

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have nested list, which looks something like this `[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]`. How can i sum numbers (in this case ones) between separators (in this case zeros)to get output like this: `[[1,2], [3,1]]`?

EDIT
And what about situation, in which the list starts with 0 and has more groups of ones? for example `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]` --> `[1, 2, 2]`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What if there's a leading zero - how does that contribute to a sum?  What about `[ [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] , ... ]` does this sum to `[1,1,1]` ?

Comment: There might be a leading zero, but you will still sum numbers between them( [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] --> [2, 1])

Answer (score 3):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]

separator = 0
result = [[sum(v) for k, v in groupby(element, key=lambda x: x != separator) if k] for element in data]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
from itertools import groupby
for i in a:
    temp=[]
    for group,lis in groupby(i):
        x=sum(lis)
        if x:
            temp.append(x)
    print(temp)
```

Or in the condensed form

```
[[sum(lis) for grp,lis in groupby(i) if grp !=0] for i in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Sum before and after the index of the separator:

```
a = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]

for i in a:
    b = i.index(0)
    e = [sum(i[:b]),sum(i[b:])]
    print(e)
```

#### Output:

```
[1, 2]
[3, 1]
```

#### An edit to handle the test case in the comment:

```
a = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0,0,1,1,0,1]]
t = []

for j in a:
    b = [i for i,x in enumerate(j) if x == 0]
    for z in b:
        t.append([sum(j[:z]), sum(j[z:])])

t = set([tuple(i) for i in t if 0 not in i])

print(t)
```

#### Output:

```
{(1, 2), (3, 1), (2, 1)}
```